# Laravel: if I neet to get data from other site should i make a route wirh get or post?

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to implement payment by card in a laravel project. After i enter the card details the payment site must to redirect to my site with infos about payment.

For this i made a route like this

```html
Route::post('/mobilpay/mobilpay/back', 'HomepageController@back');
```

I put also in VerifyCfsrTocken.php the code

```html
protected $except = [
        'ipn/*',       
        'mobilpay/*',
        
        //
    ];
```

After i enter the card details i get the error:

```html
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Is a problem with my route? Should I make a route with get and not with post?

Thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure your ipn method is post?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you made the request at the frontend. You should either make a form post request or make an ajax post request. 
Please do check your frontend

Comment: The flow is blocked before back function. 
public function back(Request $request) {
 dd($request);

Comment: You should check the code at where you enter your card details. Which is most probably in your blade file or your javascript. The error message is telling you that, your route accept only `POST` method, but it is receiving a `GET` request

Comment: i send the infos with post     <form name="frmPaymentRedirect" method="post" action="<?php echo $paymentUrl;?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="env_key" value="<?php echo $key;?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $data;?>"/>
 

 </form>

Comment: Just a side note, you ca actually use the symbol `{{$paymentUrl}}` instead of `<?php echo $paymentUrl?>`. Can you share your `routes/web.php` and also your controller file?

Comment: I put them in a comment to my question